# How to dynamically map through a firebase array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, routes, next.js

Ok, I'm building a next.js App and I'm stuck where I need to fetch unique li item from the firebase as I click a button. In the first page i have the item titles, so when I click, I want to open that title body using dynamic routing. But firebase does not give number value for their id

This is my code

For the index.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tBnk.png)

Then it should return this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9TkH.png)

The item.id above gave me some random string and numbers as an id, which i cannot use for map through it dynamically when I open each file

I tried this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLSwh.png)

But didn't work

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.